# Getting repeats using offset with current region

Tags: excel, vba

I believe my issue is the use of `currentregion` but i'm not sure what the alternative is. I've worked a bit with areas and perhaps that is the way to go in the long run, but If I can get a clear answer to this repeat issue it would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub AddAmounts()

Dim AA As Range
Dim Total As Integer

Set AA = Cells(1, 3).CurrentRegion

Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(AA)
    Debug.Print Total

AA.Offset(, -1) = Total

End Sub
```

I would like the total to end up in cell `B1`, which does occur, but unfortunatley I also get the result in cells `B2` & `B3` & `B4`

Image of result and desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're offsetting a region.  Since you want to offset the first cell in that region, you should be able to do:

```
AA.Cells(1).Offset(, -1) = Total
```

Edit: To hopefully clarify the `Cells()` bit:

```
Sub AddAmounts()
Dim AA As Range
Set AA = Cells(1, 3).CurrentRegion

AA.Offset(, -1).Select ' Compare this, to the next line
AA.Cells(1).Offset(,-1).Select ' ...and the next
AA.Cells(3).Offset(,-1).Select    
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that worked great. I need to understand why AA.Cells(1) is necessary to achieve my end goal.  My understanding at this point is that AA as the range is 'set' so I'm not sure why I need to, as I'm interpreting this, set the range for AA again?

Comment: @officemanager2 - When you first set `AA`, you set it to a `CurrentRegion` which is more than one cell.  Let's say it's `C5:N15`.  When you do `AA.Cells(1)`, this refers to the first cell *within* the `AA` range.  This would be `C5`.  `AA.Cells(2)` would be `D5`, etc. (as you increase `Cells()`, it moves first by column, then row).  If you simply offset `AA`, then it's offsetting the *whole range*, where you just want a single cell to be offset.

Comment: Ok, if I understand your feed back, the location of the final sum is arrived upon using offset, but I was not supplying the offset with the specific location to work from so instead the entire CurrentRegion was being used.  I've been trying different locations with both the Cells(1) and the Offset. Thank you for the clear follow up.

Comment: @officemanager2 - Yep! I added some code just for your testing, if you step through it with `F8`, it'll select the different ranges so you can see visually what it's referring to.